# Solving a Logic Puzzle with Answer Set Programming

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

Disclaimer: I am almost entirely new to clingo, and answer set programming in general.

I am trying to solve a [grid logic puzzle](http://www.logic-puzzles.org/) using clingo. To start, I want to generate all models that include one instance of each category.

For example, if there are three people: 
    `person(a; b; c).`, 
three houses: `house(w; x; z).`,
and three colors: 
    `color(r; g; y).`

I would want one potential stable model to be 
`assign(a, r, x), assign(b, g, z), assign(c, y, w)`
and another potential stable model to be
`assign(a, g, w), assign(b, y, z), assign(c, r, x)`, etc. That is, each person appears exactly once and likewise for the colors. I figure that once I have these models I can use constraints to eliminate models until the puzzle is solved.

I have tried using choice rules and constraints:

```
{assign(P, C, H)} :- person(P), color(C), house(H).
P1=P2 :- assign(P1, C, H), assign(P2, C, H).
```

But this is not quite scalable to large puzzles with many variables. Can anyone advise of a better way of doing this?

Comment: You should change your title.  ASP can refer to Active Server Pages, a highly trafficked topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You use `;` in `persons` and `house`, but you use `,` for `color` which is very different. Look at what `clingo --text <yourprogramfile>` gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wanted to write `color(r;g;y).` how about the following?

`% assign each house exactly one person/color
1 {assign(P, C, H) : person(P), color(C) } 1 :- house(H).
% assign each person exactly one house/color
1 {assign(P, C, H) : house(H), color(C) } 1 :- person(P).
% assign each color exactly one person/house
1 {assign(P, C, H) : house(H), person(P) } 1 :- color(C).`